# Shortcut to get Actions (Cmd+ Shift + A) not working in Intellij Idea

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working with the following versions

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.5
```

As soon as I upgraded my macos version to Mojave, from then onwards, I have started getting a weird error in Intellij which I did not face till now. When I press the shortcut (Cmd+ Shift + A)  to open the `Actions` , a terminal is opened with the message

```
close ot: nothing appropriate
```

[image]

I tried the command `man apropos` and `man makewhatis` but it did not help. Can anyone please suggest me a way to fix this ? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the macos update to Mojave, a new keyboard shrortcut was added. So going to `Keyboard` and disabling this shortcut helps resolve this issue. More information regarding the issue and the discussion can be found in this link 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003430700--Apropos-terminal-pops-up-when-typing-cmd-shift-A-to-get-actions-bar